# Copy image alt text and paste into div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple images on page wrapped with div. I want to copy image alt text and paste it into next img-txt div.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="kakka.jpg" alt="Text">
  <div class="img-txt"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="kakka2.jpg" alt="Text2">
  <div class="img-txt"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is that I get first alt text to everywhere. I know this is easy, but i can't get this working...

```
$(".container").each(function(i) {
  var alt = $("img").attr("alt");
  $(".img-txt").text(alt);
});
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Do you want to achieve something like this. <div class="img-txt">(alt value here)</div>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with your code is, traversing to correct sibling and then getting the alt text.

A smarter solution would be, using callback function of `.text()` along with traversing to sibling img element here:

```
$(".container .img-txt").text(function() {
   return $(this).siblings('img').attr("alt");
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9L9csghe/)**

Comment: I guess, in this particular case, you don't need argument `i` in callback :)

Comment: Yes. can be omitted :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you're selecting *all* the `img` and `.img-txt` elements in each iteration of the loop. Calling `attr()` on a collection of elements will only retrieve the attribute from the *first* element in that set.

You instead need to use the `this` keyword to reference the current element in the `each()` loop to find the elements within it:

```
$(".container").each(function() {
  var alt = $(this).find("img").prop("alt");
  $(this).find(".img-txt").text(alt);
});
```

You can however shorten this by providing a function to `text()` which is excuted against each matching element instance:

```js
$(".container .img-txt").text(function() {
  return $(this).prev('img').prop('alt');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="kakka.jpg" alt="Text">
  <div class="img-txt"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="kakka2.jpg" alt="Text2">
  <div class="img-txt"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".container").each(function(i) {
  var alt = $(this).children('img').attr("alt");
  $(this).children('.img-txt').text(alt);
});
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you got another way to copy the alt img into the div:

```js
$("img").each(function(i) {
    $(this).next().html($(this).attr("alt"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="kakka.jpg" alt="Text">
  <div class="img-txt"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="kakka2.jpg" alt="Text2">
  <div class="img-txt"></div>
</div>
```